# How to change the invoice number in Zen Cart

Tags: php, sql, cart, zen

I have a client who runs a Zen Cart website. He lost contact with his regular support-guy and I took over. I have little Zen Cart knowledge but great PHP/SQL/Front-End knowledge.

My client asked to change the **invoice number** back to 1 to start 2016 fresh.

I tried changed the order number in 'Shop manager' by creating a dummy order and changing that ID but he told me that's the wrong ID. There's a difference between order numbers and invoice numbers, he said.

Anyone know where I can change the Invoice number and not the Order number?

Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having used zen-cart for a number of years, out of the box there is no separate invoice number from the order number.  it is entirely possible that he contracted someone else to add an invoice number, in which case i would look at the orders table to reset it.

the order number can be reset from the admin side using tools -> store manager page.

Comment: I thought it would be something like that.